# Sorting and showing part of an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have been looking online and on the web for about a week trying to find a solution to my dilema, and so far nothing I'm doing seems to be working. I apologize in advance if I give too much code as an example!!!

Here is a snippet my array:

```
$products = array(
1 => array(
'category' => 'Computer Science',
'title' => 'Programming PHP',
'author' => 'Lerdorf',
'publisher' => 'O\'Reilly',
'price' => 29.99,
'isbn' => '1412359370'
),
2 => array(
'category' => 'Computer Science',
'title' => 'CGI Programming',
'author' => 'Guelich',
'publisher' => 'O\'Reilly',
'price' => 39.99,
'isbn' => '1772355179'
),
```

I am trying to call the 'category' and 'author' out of it, so when the user clicks on "Computer Science" within the list of books on the page, "Programming PHP" and "CGI Programming" will come up, same thing if they click on the author's name, only his books will show, etc...

I am displaying the array within my page by using a loop to call the array and display all the products within a table:

```
echo "<p>
    <a href='http://bctdigital.com/~student4/php/amazon_new.php'>AmaNot</a></p>";

echo "<h3>Our Products</h3>";

echo"<table style='width:500px;' cellspacing='0'>";
echo"<tr>
    <th style ='border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'>Title</th>
    <th style ='border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'>Price</th>
    <th style ='border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'><a href='http://bctdigital.com/~student4/php/amazon_new.php?view_product=$category'>" . $product['category'] . "</a>Category</th>
    <th style ='border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'>Author</th>
</tr>";

// Loop to display all products - work on this links
foreach($products as $id => $product)
    {
    echo "<tr> 
    <td style ='border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'><a href='http://bctdigital.com/~student4/php/amazon_new.php?view_product=$id'>" . $product['title'] . "</a></td>
    <td style ='border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'>$" . $product['price'] . " </td> 
    <td style ='border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'><a href='http://bctdigital.com/~student4/php/amazon_new.php?view_category=$title'>" . $product['category'] . "</td>
    <td style ='border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'>" . $product['author'] . "</td>
    </tr>";
}
echo"</table>";
}
```

This seems to be working just fine, however, figuring out how to call part of the array and show it is where I am having the issues.

Attached is the URL so you can see what I'm building (it's for a school project), for some reason I could figure out all the other more complicated parts, and what doesn't seem to be the most difficult is what's giving me the most trouble! Go figure!
Please let me know if anything else needs to be shown that I didn't show. I put in the snippets of code where I "think" the sorting function should go.
http://bctdigital.com/~student4/php/amazon_new.php

Comment: Do these entries come from a database query?

Comment: No, and I think this is where I'm having a problem, we aren't using a database per se (as in mysql), we are using an external php file (products.php) which contains the array and the information, that is loaded first in the page with a require("products.php");

Comment: Try using `$_GET` to determine if `?view_category` is set, then sort if `$product['category']` equals `$_GET['view_category']` -- that way, you can work with only the entries that match. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

To use a custom sort for your array, you should use the [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.usort.php) function.
You could end up with something like this, for the category sort :

```
usort($products, function cmp($a, $b) {
     if ($a['category'] == $b['category']) {
        return 0;

     return ($a['category'] < $b['category']) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: How can I call this function? (Also I'm assuming that I add this above the code calling the array into the table).

Comment: OK, i re-read your post and you don't want to sort your array at all.

You want to FILTER it, that's an different problem.
See the answer of armadadrive for this.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the superglobal `$_GET` variable to determine the category. From there, use that variable as a conditional test when looping through your array. Only display the results that are part of the chosen category. For instance:

```
if (isset($_GET['view_category']) {
    //store the category (e.g. what comes after ?view_category= in the URL)
    $cat = $_GET['view_category'];

    //loop through and use only those entries which match the category that was clicked
    foreach ($products as $id => $product) {
        if ($product['category'] == $cat) {
            //display this entry and other details, etc.
        }
        else continue;
    }
}
```

Looking at your website, you'll need your links under the Category header to add their value on the other side of `?view_category=` so that the corresponding entry shows up in the URL and are available to `$_GET`.

Comment: It's likely that there is a PHP error. My answer is not meant to simply be copy and pasted; it exists to give you an idea of what kind of logic you could put in place to solve your issue. Where are you placing this code?

Comment: I placed it above the code that calls the array into the table (shown in my original question)

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the beginning of your PHP script and see what output errors occur after you refresh. Perhaps there is some logic error or simply a syntax issue.

Answer (score 0):

you haven't declared $title anywhere above

```
<td style ='border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'><a href='http://bctdigital.com/~student4/php/amazon_new.php?view_category=$title'>" . $product['category'] . "</td>
```

I think, it should be

```
<td style ='border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'><a href='http://bctdigital.com/~student4/php/amazon_new.php?view_category=".$product['category']."'>" . $product['category'] . "</td>
```

Further you need to add:

```
if(isset($_GET['view_category']) && $_GET['view_category']!=''){
 // here you have to pull data for the particular category and display it....
}
```

Comment: Ok this is really close!, it is def. changing the URL to be either Business or Computer Science, however, it's not pulling the information out of the array that I can see...
The title, pulls up just the title clicked on and the information for that title.

Comment: Now that you've managed to add the category into the URL, check what it is with `$_GET['view_category']` and put an `if` statement in that works with only those results matching the category. @Neo and my answer combined should get you rocking and rolling.

Comment: ok, I added the if statement, and it is opening up another page, just not pulling in the array information, now I have been using this to pull up the array for all the information within the array:
if(isset($_GET['view_product'])) {
 $product_id = $_GET['view_product'];
should I do something similar?

Comment: ok, that is the code that seems to be causing the page to go blank, I just need to try and work on it a bit, thanks!!!

Comment: If either @Neo or I have solved the problem for you, please consider upvoting and accepting the answer by clicking the check mark.

Comment: can you show the full code? which is causing a 'blank' page

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to do it.

1. GET
2. Ajax

GET is global variables, so you can use it $_GET.
for this your link has to be `<td style ='border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'><a href='http://bctdigital.com/~student4/php/amazon_new.php?view_category=".$product['category']."'>" . $product['category'] . "</td>`
then you can access variable $_GET['view_category'].
this should work for any category.

with the ajax park you can just send category as param to the url where you can have this logic

```
$products = array(
1 => array(
'category' => 'Computer Science',
'title' => 'Programming PHP',
'author' => 'Lerdorf',
'publisher' => 'O\'Reilly',
'price' => 29.99,
'isbn' => '1412359370'
),
2 => array(
'category' => 'Computer Science',
'title' => 'CGI Programming',
'author' => 'Guelich',
'publisher' => 'O\'Reilly',
'price' => 39.99,
'isbn' => '1772355179'
));

$category = $_GET['view_category'];
foreach ($products as $prodArray){

    if($prodArray['category'] == $category){

                //your display goes here
        echo "Title: " . $prodArray['title'] . "<br>";
        echo "Author: " . $prodArray['author'] . "<br>";

    }

}
```